# Sticky notes won't open Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, stickynotes

I installed sticky notes on my Ubuntu 17.10 using following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
```

And after I installed it, it shows as an app. But it doesn't open. When I click it, nothing happens.

Why is that? How can I run sticky notes on my PC ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands listed here doesn't work on my Ubuntu v17.10 either. If you still wish to use sticky notes, better alternative is to install 'xpad'.

The steps and commands to install xpad are as follows:

- Update the packages and repositories:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install xpad using the command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xpad
  ```

Once the processing is done, 'xpad' gets installed successfully on your linux system. To check the same, you can use this command:

```
sudo dpkg -l xpad
```

I hope you find 'xpad' as the best alternative to sticky notes.

Regards.

Comment: THis is an amazing solution, thanks for sharing it! :)

Comment: Happy to help, @pimguilherme 

Let know your experience with "xpad"

Answer (score 0):

`indicator-sticknotes` fails to show in the task bar the first time I start it.

If I try to start it again from the command line it says `indicator-stickynotes` is already running. This works to restore proper functionality...

```
sudo pkill indicator && indicator-stickynotes
```

Not sure why it hangs initially.